# Why isn't my WPF Popup Showing Where it Should

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid, popup

I am trying to follow this guide : http://www.jarloo.com/excel-like-autofilter-in-wpf/ to add a small popup when a button in a datagrid column header is pressed. I have added a filter button and icon to the column header and set the popup's placement target as this button but the popup always displays at the bottom left of the whole window.

Any idea's why?

**DataGrid Column**

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images\bios.png" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Model" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="3"/>
                <Button Name="btnModelFilter" Margin="3,0,0,0" Click="btnModelFilter_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Source="Images\filter.png" Width="10" Height="10"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>                    
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Popup**

```
<Popup Name="popModel" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnModelFilter}" StaysOpen="False" Width="200">
    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
        <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,15">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,15">
                <Button Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="btnSelectAll" Click="btnSelectAll_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="Select All" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>

                <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Name="btnUnselectAll" Click="btnUnselectAll_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="Select None" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>

            <ListBox x:Name="lstModels" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Item}" Checked="ApplyFilters" Unchecked="ApplyFilters" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 2):

since the Name attribute of your button is defined within a DataTemplate, the scope of the name does not go beyond that DataTemplate, hence the button is not found and PopUp is displayed at 0,0.
 This scope rule is logical because imagine if you re-use the DataTemplate several times, then having same button name would raise a compiler error.
You might define your PopUp as a style with a key, and include it in your Header DataTemplate directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your popup is in the same stack panel of your `btnModelFilter`, I think your StackPanel (parent of the `btnModelFilter`) should be the placement target of the popup and **not** the `btnModelFilter`.